Examples of statements provable in PA whose corresponding propositional tautologies don't seem to admit short extended Frege proofs
Bounded arithmetic has been studied because if a statement provable using certain forms of bounded arithmetic is transformed into a family of propositional tautologies (which can be done if the statement is of a certain form), the proof can be transformed into a family of polynomially-long proofs in certain propositional proof systems. For example, as I understand, a theorem by Cook (see Wikipedia) states that this is true for a bounded arithmetic theory called $S_2^1$, statements of the form $\forall x \phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is in a set of admissible formulas denoted by $\Pi_1^b$, and extended Frege systems.
What is a plausible counterexample to that theorem if $S_2^1$ were to be replaced by all of $PA$? In other words, what is an example of a statement provable in PA (but not $S_2^1$) and convertible into a family of propositional tautologies as in the Cook theorem, where the propositional tautologies don't appear to admit a polynomially long sequence of extended Frege proofs?
